# Why sed does not add string in the file line?

Tags: macos, sed

I am trying to add a new line with some string (`\mu`) at the beginning of a file using OSX sed.
Now I can do it for common text and numbers. But for symbols it does not work.

```
sed -i -e '1s/^/\\mu/' file
```

This adds `mu` but not `\mu`.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Sorry. `sed -i -e '1s/^/\\mu/' file` works for you? Are you using GNU sed?

Comment: Okay. I checked. It works for GNU sed but not for OSX sed. I should edit my question then.

Answer (score 0):

I executed `sed -i -e '1s/^/\\mu/' ./file` on OSX 10.13.6 (latest Xtools, I think), Darwin 17.7.0. 
I did notice that the generation of duplicates files for different variants of the command was anomalous. Let me explain,

```
sed -i -e 's/^/\\mu/' ./tmp.txt
```

i.e. placing "\mu" on each new line. 
Output in file "tmp.txt",

```
    \mulease 192.168.234.5 {
    \mu  starts 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
    \mu  ends 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
    \mu  tstp 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
    \mu  cltt 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
etc...
```

If I execute the command you want,

```
sed -i -e '1s/^/\\mu/' ./tmp.txt
```

Output in file "tmp.txt"

```
    \mulease 192.168.234.5 {
      starts 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
      ends 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
      tstp 3 2018/11/21 18:54:11;
      cltt 3 2018/11/21 18:53:11;
...etc
```

The old file "tmp.txt" is now duplicated and becomes 'tmp 3.txt', whilst the latest version tmp.txt has been correctly edited. Introducing a space into the file name isn't cool ('tmp 3.txt) AND why start at 3?
Hope it helps.

Comment: I have same OSX and latest Xtools. I can see that it is now giving result. I still don't know what happened previously. But at the same time I have one more extra file created with `file-e`. On OSX I see that that `-e` is always needed unlike GNU sed. This extra file seems unnecessary.